# Search in array of objects that sits in object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to check if bidder *"one"* already has *"placementId": "4"* in *arr*.
I've tried to combine for loop with filter with no luck. Is there any elegant way to solve this?

```
var check = { "one": "4" },
    arr = [{
        "code": "qwe",
        "bids": [{
                "bidder": "one",
                "params": {
                    "placementId": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "bidder": "two",
                "params": {
                    "placementId": "2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "code": "asd",
        "bids": [{
            "bidder": "one",
            "params": {
                "placementId": "3"
            }
        }]
    }];
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `find()` is the way to go here. You want to find an element in your array where one of the bids has a `bid.bidder` of "one" and `bid.params.placementId` of 4. Or `undefined` if it doesn't exist.

This can be expressed in javascript with something like:

```
let found = arr.find(code => 
            code.bids.some(bid => bid.bidder === "one" && bid.params.placementId === "4"))
```

Since you only want to know whether it exists or not you basically only care if it returns something or undefined. Here's a positive and negative example:

```js
var check = { "one": "1" },arr = [{"code": "qwe","bids": [{"bidder": "one","params": {"placementId": "1"}},{"bidder": "two","params": {"placementId": "2"}}]}, {"code": "asd","bids": [{"bidder": "one","params": {"placementId": "3"}}]}];

// user one placement id 4 does not exist
let found = arr.find(code => code.bids.some(bid => bid.bidder === "one" && bid.params.placementId === "4"))
console.log(found !==  undefined)

// user two placement id 2 does exist
found = arr.find(code => code.bids.some(bid => bid.bidder === "two" && bid.params.placementId === "2"))
console.log(found !==  undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
arr.forEach(element => {
    element.bids.forEach(item=>{
        if(item.bidder == Object.keys(check)[0]){
            if(item.params.placementId == 1){
               console.log("bidder 1 and placementId 1 found");
            }
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bidders = {};
arr.forEach((field)=>{
    let bidArray = field.bids.map((bids)=>{
        if(bidders[bids.bidder] === undefined){
            bidders[bids.bidder] = [] 
        }

        return {bidder:bids.bidder,placementId:bids.params.placementId};
    })
    for(let placement of bidArray){
        bidders[placement.bidder].push(placement.placementId);
    }
})
console.log(bidders);
```

To list out all the bidders and their respective placements

then you can do

```
if(bidders.one.indexOf(4) !== -1){
console.log('Placement 4 is taken by bidder 1.');
}
else{
console.log('Placement 4 is not taken by bidder 1.');
}
```